# Can't update Android app with new Unity Build, package appears to be corrupt

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

We have a new build of our app that was developed in Unity 2019 2.11. This will replace our app that was originally developed in Xamarin. 
When trying to update the app on a device we get the following message.

> App not installed
>   The package appears to be corrupt

If I uninstall the current app first and then install the new one, it works fine. I'm using the same keystore and app name in both apps.

Comment: What about your build number? Your updated version should have larger build number than previous one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out there were 2 issues.

1. The version of the new build was lower than the installed build.
2. The keystore being used to sign the new build was different from the keystore used for the prod build.